# VSCode error "an incorrect number of function arguments has been passed" for function passed as a parameter in Julia

Tags: visual-studio-code, functional-programming, julia

VSCode detects a problem with the statement `compare(left, right)` in the below Advent of Code program:

```
function intcode_comparison(vm::VM, compare::Function)
    left, right = intcode_parameters(vm, 1:2)
    dst = intcode_parameter(vm, 3, true);
    intcode_write(vm, dst, Int(compare(left, right)))
    return nextInstruction(vm)
end

function intcodeLessThan(vm::VM)
    return intcode_comparison(vm, <)
end

function intcodeEquals(vm::VM)
    return intcode_comparison(vm, ==)
end
```

The problem description is "*an incorrect number of function arguments has been passed*."

I searched my computer for a Julia program that contains a more specific type of function (`Get-ChildItem 'C:\Program Files\Julia-1.3.0\' *.jl -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "::Function"`). It looks like they all use the plain type `::Function` for functions passed as parameters.

Is there anything that I can or should do to make this error go away?

Comment: Julia decides whether or not the expression

 compare(left, right)
has the correct number of parameters based on the argument number of the one or more functions that have a name the same as the value of the compare variable. You might need to do something such as

println(compare)
and check the arguments to the function that statement names.